# Abstract Classes and Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, abstract-class

I am trying to understand how can I implement dependency injection, but I have some questions:

1. Can I use abstract classes? I read some articles about DI and if I understand it well, they say that you have to use interfaces but not abstract classes - how can I avoid using duplicated code in different classes?
2. If I have many dependencies in a class, do I have to inject all of them in the constructor? What if I don't use all of them in all methods?
3. Can I instance objects? If I don't instance objects, how could I invoke the constructor of a class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I use abstract classes?

Yes. However, in practice, there may be some advantages to using interfaces. For example, it's sometimes easier to mock interfaces than abstract classes when you are testing. I would also ask why you feel the need to use abstract classes instead of interfaces, but that leads to the next point...

> How can I avoid using duplicated code in different classes?

In general you should [favor composition over inheritence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) for code reuse.

> If I have many dependencies in a class, do I have to inject all of them in the constructor?

No, there are other ways to inject a dependency, such as a method. But I would say constructor injection is the "classic" DI pattern, and it has some advantages. For example, if you inject all dependencies in the constructor, then you don't need to worry about someone calling a method on your class before the required dependencies have been set up.

> What if I don't use all of them in all methods?

That is OK on a small scale. However, if you have lots of dependencies or lots of methods, that may be a sign that your class is doing too much. This is especially true if you have distinct groups of methods/dependencies (e.g. if methods A, B, C use dependencies 1, 2 and methods D, E, F use dependencies 3, 4). See  [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

> Can I instance objects? If I don't instance objects, how could I invoke the constructor of a class?

It's important to think about different types of classes. You don't need to use DI for simple POCO classes that simply hold data--feel free to `new` them up as needed. However, DI is very important for service-type classes that perform some business logic or interact with some external system like a database. In that case, you should *not* use `new` to instantiate them in your classes.

Of course, you will have to instantiate these objects at some point. But the point of DI is that the class that depends on X should not also instantiate X. Dependency injection frameworks often have a "composition root" where all the dependencies are wired up. That's where you would see new instances being created.

Comment: This is a great answer. It focused on all the underlying issues that lead to OP's questions.

Comment: @Pablo - please vote and accept (if you are satisfied with the answer) rather than commenting "thanks." See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Short answers:

1. DI just a pattern that allow create dependent outside of a class. So as I know, you can use abstract class, depend on how you imp container.
2. You can `inject` via other methods. (constructor just one in many ways).
3. You shoud use lib or imp your container. In common, they use `decorator` to save description about dependency, then you use it to create instance.

Answer (score 0):

## Abstract classes

> 1- Can i use abstract classes? I read some articles about DI and, if i understanded well, they say that u have to use interface but not abstract classes but how can i avoid to use duplicated code in diferent classes?

I think you're talking about 2 different things.

A. You can use abstract classes and you don't have to use interfaces. Here's an example.

```
internal abstract class BaseService
{
    public abstract string GetString();
}

internal class ServiceC : BaseService
{
    public override string GetString() => "ServiceB";
}

internal class ServiceD
{
    public ServiceD(BaseService baseService) { BaseService = baseService; }
    public BaseService BaseService { get; }

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    // ServiceCollection is package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddSingleton<BaseService, ServiceC>()
        .AddSingleton<ServiceD>()
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    var serviceC = serviceProvider.GetService<BaseService>(); 

    var serviceD = serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceD>();

    //serviceD.BaseService is ServiceC
```

B. Even when you use Interfaces, you can still use abstract classes, for the not-DI parts.

Please consider the following example.

```
internal abstract class BaseService { protected string GetCommon() => "Common functionality"; }

internal interface IServiceA { string GetA(); }

internal interface IServiceB { string GetB(); }


internal class ServiceA : BaseService, IServiceA
{
    public string GetA() => "A + " + GetCommon();
}

internal class ServiceB : BaseService, IServiceB
{
    public string GetB() => "B + " + GetCommon();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    // ServiceCollection is package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddSingleton<IServiceA, ServiceA>()
        .AddSingleton<IServiceB, ServiceB>()
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    var serviceA = serviceProvider.GetService<IServiceA>();

    Console.WriteLine(serviceA.GetA()); // "A + Common functionality"

    Console.WriteLine(serviceProvider.GetService<IServiceB>().GetB()); // B + Common functionality

}
```

## Only constructor?

You can take extra dependencies in methods.

```
internal class ServiceE
{
    private readonly IServiceA a;

    public ServiceE(IServiceA a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public string AandB(IServiceB b) => a.GetA() + b.GetB();
}
```